# Querying data from a specific related object in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to use Django to display a table of information from across several models and I'm uncertain what the best practices for doing so are.  Here's a stripped down version of my models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Widget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pass

class Finished_Widget(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    thing = models.ForeignKey(Thing)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
```

It's a pretty simple setup with the User and the Widget being connected through an unknown number of Finished_Widget objects.  What I'd like to show in my html is a list of instances of the Widget names and the date of the most recent finished widget.  Obviously the below code doesn't work, but hopefully it'll illustrate what data I'm looking to have output.

```
{% for widget in widget_list %}
<p>{{ widget.name }}</p>
<p>{{ widget__Finished_Widget.latest.created }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I've thought about a number of different approaches to the problem, including:

- appending the desired date as an additional attribute via the view
- creating a dictionary in the view and calling that in the template
- the ManyToManyField using the 'through' argument
- adding meta to the Widget calling to the created date of the latest Finished_Widget

Unfortunately I haven't been able to make any of these work, and I'm not sure which, if any, are even on the right path.

Note: I've found quite a few variations on this problem on SO already which makes this pretty close to a dupe, but they don't seem to have helped me much because of the need to narrow down the Finished_Widget list to those matching the user ID, matching the Widget ID, **and** only the latest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer based on need for passing in `user` object.

The easiest way is to deal with this in your view, but it has its problems.

```
for widget in widget_list:
    widget.latest_finished_widget = widget.finished_widget_set.filter(user=request.user).latest('created')

{% for widget in widget_list %}
    <p>{{ widget.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ widget.latest_finished_widget }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

While this code is easy to write, it suffers from executing a db query for every iteration.

One quick solution is called query partitioning. Use 2 queries and python to populate the reverse relationship as efficiently as possible without going to SQL.

```
widgets = Widget.objects.filter(...)

finished_widget_map = dict( 
    [(x['thing__id'], x['created']) for x in 
        Finished_Widget.objects.filter(thing__in=widgets, user=request.user).values_list('thing__id', 'created').order_by('created')])
    # this ensures we only select what we need, thing__id and the created column
    # ordering by created will ensure only the last (latest) will appear in our dictionary

for widget in widgets:
    widget.latest_finished_widget_created = finished_widget_map.get(widget.id, 'No Widget')


{% for widget in widgets %}
    {{ widget.name }}
    {{ widget.latest_finished_widget_created }}
{% endfor %}
```

There are always tradeoffs though. This could potentially be slow if there are many many Finished_Widgets python is pointlessly trying to populate a dict with.

Comment: Yuji, I think you might have accidentally highlighted why I'm having so much trouble with this.  Can you explain where you're getting 'finished_widget_set' from?  It looks like it might be some aspect of django template syntax that I can't find the documentation on?  Or are you assuming I'll be defining that elsewhere?

Comment: @IanWhalen, great question! Yes, django automatically generates convenience methods for retrieving relations "backwards" http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward -- by default: fieldname_set. Still, it's inefficient as you might imagine 1 query per widget.  It's more useful when you have one object and want all 100 related objects, not 100 objects each with 1 related object you'd like.

Comment: PS: template dot notation is strictly python based and there is no special template syntax, aside from the dot notation : ) http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#render It does python dict lookup, attr lookup, index lookup, then fails silently. So if there's a dot notation method you don't recognize, it's a python dict key, attr, or index!

Comment: Hey Yuji, I hate to 'un-answer' this but I realized there's a fairly big problem with the first suggestion you gave.  The part 'widget.finished_widget_set.latest' will return the latest finished_widget from across the whole database, whereas I need it to only show the latest for the currently authenticated user.  I'm blocked, however, by the fact that you cannot pass in arguments within the template so 'widget.finished_widget_set(user=user).latest' won't work.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @IanWhalen: then you would have to set an attribute on your object (model methods shouldn't deal with the request) via your view. I would highly suggest the second method I pointed out though regardless! Updated examples

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think there's quite enough information here to completely answer your question, but one simple solution to the issue of returning only the most recent Finished_Widget would be to add a method called "latest_widget" to the User model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    #...
    def latest_widget(self):
        return self.widgets.all().order_by('-created')[0]
```

You could technically add this to the Finished_Widget model, though it doesn't make as much sense. If you're using the User model from Django's auth module, you would probably want to subclass the model in order to add this functionality.

Once you have this method, calling it from the template is simple. If you had a list of Users, for example, called user_list, you could display each user and his/her latest widget like this:

```
{% for uu in user_list %}
<p>
    {{uu.username}}: {{uu.latest_widget.name}}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, Walter, but I'll be iterating over a list of Widgets, not Users, and I'll be looking to access the 'created' Field from the latest Finished_Widget object, not the latest Widget object.

Comment: He appears to be iterating over `widget_list` which are presumably `Widget` instances -- so it would have to go in there. Your idea works regardless, though :) edit: browser refresh fail

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that now. Well, for me the most helpful thing for formulating a solution would be to see some sample data (as it is lives in your models & db) and how it should appear on the page.